# How do I write character ALT-0146 to an XML file using Perl?

Tags: html, xml, windows, perl, utf-8

’

That is the character, and I cannot find a way to detect, replace, or write it properly to an XML file. At first I was using string concatenation, then I wisened up to XML::Writer, but it still won't work, the XML is still broken afterward.(Need it in UTF-8)

This is a test I wrote that still breaks:

```
    my $output = new IO::File(">$foundFilePath");
    my $writer = new XML::Writer(OUTPUT => $output);
    $writer->xmlDecl("UTF-8");
    $writer->startTag("xml");
    $writer->startTag("test");
    $writer->characters("’");
    $writer->endTag("test");
    $writer->endTag("xml");
    $writer->end();
    $output->close();
```

To be more specific, I am trying to get the data from this page: http://investing.businessweek.com/businessweek/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=4439466

And Mr. William O’Keefe is messing everything up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you need to do.  If you want to write UTF-8 to a file, you need to say so:

```
my $output = IO::File->new($foundFilePath, ">:utf8");
```

And if you want to use literal UTF-8 strings in your source code, you need to say

```
use utf8;
```

at the beginning of your program.  Otherwise, Perl assumes your source code is Latin-1.

Here's a complete example script:

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::File;
use XML::Writer;

my $foundFilePath = 'test.xml';
my $output = IO::File->new($foundFilePath, ">:utf8");
my $writer = XML::Writer->new(OUTPUT => $output);
$writer->xmlDecl("UTF-8");
$writer->startTag("xml");
$writer->startTag("test");
$writer->characters("’");
$writer->endTag("test");
$writer->endTag("xml");
$writer->end();
$output->close();
```

Comment: Alternatively, `$writer->characters(chr(0x2019));` and `$writer->characters("\x{2019}");` are less likely to get mangled by editors.

Comment: That helps in creating the character, but the main problem I have is detecting it in the first place, how can I actually catch the character with a regex?

Comment: Though really, if you just have all your input and output using utf8, there's no need to detect it -- it'll all just work.

Comment: @Sho, that's a separate question.  Please ask it as a new question (with more details about what you've tried) if you need an answer.

Comment: I've tried more than a few different expressions, none of them turn up anything. I might have saved and read from an html file that was accidentally in latin-1...  Could you take a look at the file and see what kind of encoding nightmare I've wound myself into? http://filevo.com/wkkixmebxlmh.html